# Custom Transformation Component templates for visual studio

Tags: liquid-xml

Transformation Components in Liquid Studio are a fixed set of components. Is it possible to develop our own components with a .net template file?

Something like Grasshopper: https://developer.rhino3d.com/api/grasshopper/html/b883d0c0-4947-48bc-8e9e-492a6d6c2a06.htm

Kind regards, Peter.

Answer (score 0):

The [Liquid XML Data Mapper](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/data-mapper) has a fixed set of components, however it is possible to create 'sub components' from the components that are provided. Once created a sub function is added to the component palette and can be re-used in the same way as any other component. Have a look at the '[Sub Components](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/Reference/XmlStudio/DataMapper_SubFunctions.html)' documentation.